# Jupyter notebook doesn't work after installing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed the tensorflow with Anaconda for a new environment. But after succesfull installation, the jupyter notebook doesn't work.

I installed with the following way:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install pandas matplotlib jupyter notebook scipy scikit-learn
pip install tensorflow
```

But when I try to start the juypyter notebook I got the following error:

```
Unable to create process using ‘C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\jupyter-script.py notebook’
```

I tried to uninstall via pip, but pip doesn't work also:

```
(C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow) C:\Users\User>pip uninstall jupyter
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\pip-script.py uninstall jupyter'
```

If i run the conda info, I get the following:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\User> conda info
Current conda install:

           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : 3.0.27
     python version : 3.6.3.final.0
   requests version : 2.18.4
   root environment : C:\Users\User\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow
   envs directories : C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                      C:\Users\User\.conda\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : C:\Users\User\.condarc
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299
      administrator : False
```

What am I did wrong, and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!